# Moving google maps marker

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, xcode8, swift3

I'm using Swift 3 and I want to create a moving marker in my map view, so that if the user touches the screen and moved the marker also moves with the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, Amir! What you already try? Do you have some code to show for us?

Answer (score 0):

Use **GMSMapViewDelegate** method :

> mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:

Set **GMSMarker** in this method at camera position.

This method call when camera position change in map.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
// Apply set marker logic here
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you give **GMSMapViewDelegate as self**